# error on Converting json data to model at controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.Net MVC 4 I need to post a json data in to controller using ajax method and convert json back to model. i am able to get json from my model, but I can't convert it back.
i got an  exception in my controller. here I create a model object that is called by another ajax method as json type. and posting this data using another ajax method.

Here is my code:

```
public class LiveController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Live/

    public JsonResult myproduct()
    {
        Product Book = new Product {pId=1,pName="Novel" };
        return Json(Book,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult viewproduct()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public String loadproduct(String Book1)
    {

        Product values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(Book1);
        return "ready";
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string pName { get; set; }
    public int pId { get; set; }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var Book;
    $('#searchbtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Live/myproduct",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {},

            success: function (result) {

                Book = result;
                $.each(result, function (key, val) {
                    $('.prolist').append("<li>" + val + "</li>");

                });
            }
        });

    });
    $('#postbtn').click(function () {

         var Book1 = JSON.stringify(Book);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Live/loadproduct",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:Book1  ,

            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please provide a  solution.

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
var Jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>("jsonstring");// pass your string json here

Product result = Jsonobject.Product;
```

Comment: shwo the json which is returned??

Comment: i have change the code as you said,but now i am getting this error:Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: j. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: i got this json : {"pId":1,"pName":"test"}

Comment: json is not well.. see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240084/how-to-convert-deserialize-json-result-with-multiple-objects-into-c-sharp-classe/23240113#23240113

Comment: At last I got the answer , I have to made a little change in the code,Thanks to Ehsan, I will post the correct answer in tomorrow, now  I have no right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me

public class LiveController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Live/

```
    public JsonResult myproduct()
    {
        Product Book = new Product {pId=1,pName="Novel" };
        return Json(Book,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult viewproduct()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult loadproduct()
    {
        var request = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request;



        request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var json= new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd(); ;




        Product result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);// pass your string json here

        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //var Jsonobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>("jsonstring"); 
        //Product result = Jsonobject;
        //return "ready";
    }
}
```

}

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    var Book;
    $('#searchbtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Live/myproduct",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {},

            success: function (result) {

                Book = result;
                $.each(result, function (key, val) {
                    $('.prolist').append("<li>" + val + "</li>");

                });
            }
        });

    });
    $('#postbtn').click(function () {


        var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(Book);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Live/loadproduct",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: jsonstring,

            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                alert(result)
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });
    });













});
```